# What is wrong with this SELECT INTO statement in my T-SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following `T-SQL` query, which is supposed to insert the output of a `Select` statement from a `View` into a `SQL` Table that does not yet exist:

```
USE MyDatabase

SELECT * INTO dbo.[QueryType2_TBL]

FROM 
     OPENDATASOURCE
       (
          'SQLOLEDB', 
          'Data Source=MyDatabase;User ID=XXX;Password=XXXXX'
       ,SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.dbo.[QueryType2]
       );
```

It seems there are syntax errors in the `T-SQL` codes but I can't figure out how to correct them. To note that QueryType2_TBL is a table that does not exist on the database. Am I doing it correctly or is there another way to do this?

Comment: What syntax error message does the system return ?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like following.

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.[QueryType2_TBL]
FROM 
     OPENDATASOURCE
       (
          'SQLOLEDB', 
          'Data Source=MyDatabase;User ID=XXX;Password=XXXXX'
      ).MyDatabase.dbo.[QueryType2]
```

You might need to check the `Data Source` and `Database Name`, you are using the same name. Your Data Source should be the ServerName/IP

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the Server Name issue. However, [Querytype2] is not a table but a View. So I need a Select statement to get the data, right?

Comment: i don't think that you need to write your query differently for the view. It should work.

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `OPENDATASOURCE` as if it were `OPENROWSET`, those 2 behave differently. Your syntax matches the one for `OPENROWSET`, which requires query as 3rd parameter (`OPENDATASET` does not).

Try with the following:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.[QueryType2_TBL]
FROM 
     OPENROWSET
       (
          'SQLOLEDB', 
          'Data Source=MyDatabase;User ID=XXX;Password=XXXXX',
          'SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.dbo.[QueryType2]'
       );
```

---

The [OPENDATASOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is used to establish a connection and use is as if it were the first part of a 4-part named convertion:

> OPENDATASOURCE ( provider_name, init_string )

For example:

```
SELECT 
    *  
FROM 
    OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI','Data Source=London\Payroll;Integrated Security=SSPI')  -- Remote server / file
        .AdventureWorks2012 -- Database
        .HumanResources     -- Schema
        .Employee           -- Table
```